# Custom Global Planner causing problems - undefined symbol

Tags: navigation, ros-melodic, nav-core, move-base, baseglobalplanner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just created a CopyPlanner as a custom Global Planner (following [this tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/Writing%20A%20Global%20Path%20Planner%20As%20Plugin%20in%20ROS)) that copies a plan from elsewhere and passes it on to the local planner. Every time I try using it as part of my application I get the following error:

```
[ INFO] [1624971783.958384719]: global_costmap: Using plugin "static_layer"
[ INFO] [1624971783.967317766]: Requesting the map...
[ INFO] [1624971784.172037054]: Resizing costmap to 2505 X 1005 at 0.050000 m/pix
[ INFO] [1624971784.270623155]: Received a 2505 X 1005 map at 0.050000 m/pix
[ INFO] [1624971784.275646093]: global_costmap: Using plugin "obstacles_layer"
[ INFO] [1624971784.279385243]:     Subscribed to Topics: scan scan2
[ INFO] [1624971784.320028943]: global_costmap: Using plugin "inflater_layer"
/opt/ros/melodic/lib/move_base/move_base: symbol lookup error: /home/jm/catkin_ws/devel/lib//libcopy_planner_lib.so: undefined symbol: _ZN18base_local_planner12CostmapModelC1ERKN10costmap_2d9Costmap2DE
[move_base-4] process has died [pid 8140, exit code 127, cmd /opt/ros/melodic/lib/move_base/move_base __name:=move_base __log:=/home/jm/.ros/log/4faf7662-d8da-11eb-90d3-046c59d9d94c/move_base-4.log].
log file: /home/jm/.ros/log/4faf7662-d8da-11eb-90d3-046c59d9d94c/move_base-4*.log
```

I have no idea what could be going wrong as I am still very new to ROS.  I found someone having the same [issue](https://answers.ros.org/question/174486/about-undefined-symbol-error/) but I don't understand what was suggested in the solution.

Here is my CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.2)
project(isaac_navigation)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED 
  COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  rospy
  std_msgs
  pluginlib
  geometry_msgs
  nav_msgs
  message_generation
  base_local_planner
)

add_message_files(
  FILES
  path.msg
)

add_service_files(
  FILES
  copier.srv
)

generate_messages(
  DEPENDENCIES
  std_msgs
  geometry_msgs
  nav_msgs
)

catkin_package(
 INCLUDE_DIRS include
 LIBRARIES isaac_navigation
 CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp rospy std_msgs message_runtime nav_msgs geometry_msgs

)

include_directories(include
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

add_library(copy_planner_lib src/copy_planner.cpp)
```

Here is my package.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package format="2">
  <name>isaac_navigation</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description>The isaac_navigation package</description>

  <maintainer email="somemail">J</maintainer>

  <license>BSD</license>

  <author email="somemail">J</author>

  <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>

  <build_depend>roslaunch</build_depend>
  <build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>
  <build_depend>rospy</build_depend>
  <build_depend>std_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>geometry_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>nav_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>message_generation</build_depend>
  <build_depend>nav_core</build_depend>



  <build_export_depend>roscpp</build_export_depend>
  <build_export_depend>rospy</build_export_depend>
  <build_export_depend>std_msgs</build_export_depend>
  <build_export_depend>nav_msgs</build_export_depend>
  <build_export_depend>geometry_msgs</build_export_depend>

  <exec_depend>roscpp</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>rospy</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>std_msgs</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>nav_msgs</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>geometry_msgs</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>map_server</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>move_base</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>message_runtime</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>nav_core</exec_depend>

  <!-- The export tag contains other, unspecified, tags -->
  <export>
    <nav_core plugin="${prefix}/copy_planner_plugin.xml" />


  </export>
</package>
```

Here is my copy_planner.xml file:

```
 <library path="lib/libcopy_planner_lib">
  <class name="copy_planner/CopyPlanner" type="copy_planner::CopyPlanner" base_class_type="nav_core::BaseGlobalPlanner">
    <description>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</description>
  </class>
 </library>
```

Here is my move_base.launch file:

```
<launch>

  <master auto="start"/>
  <!-- Run the map server -->
  <node name="map_server" pkg="map_server" type="map_server" args="/home/jm/isaac/sdk/packages/eband_ros/maps/factory.yaml"/>

  <arg name="open_rviz" default="true"/>

  <group if="$(arg open_rviz)">
    <node pkg="rviz" type="rviz" name="rviz" required="true" args="-d $(find isaac_navigation)/rviz/nav.rviz"/>
  </group>

  <!-- Setting up costmap -->
  <!-- <node name="static_tf0" pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" args="2 0 0 0 0 0 /map /base_footprint 100"/> -->

  <!-- move_base -->
  <node pkg="move_base" type="move_base" respawn="false" name="move_base" output="screen">

    <rosparam file="$(find isaac_navigation)/param/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="global_costmap" />
    <rosparam file="$(find isaac_navigation)/param/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="local_costmap" />
    <rosparam file="$(find isaac_navigation)/param/local_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <rosparam file="$(find isaac_navigation)/param/global_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <rosparam file="$(find isaac_navigation)/param/base_local_planner_params.yaml" command="load" />

    <param name="base_global_planner" value="copy_planner/CopyPlanner" />
    <param name="base_local_planner" value="eband_local_planner/EBandPlannerROS" />

  </node>
</launch>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/381371/custom-global-planner-causing-problems---undefined-symbol/) by [jmyazbeck](https://answers.ros.org/users/74848/jmyazbeck/) on ROS Answers with karma: 22 on 2021-06-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would make sure that `base_local_planner` is in your list of `CATKIN_DEPENDS` in the `catkin_package` and then add

```
target_link_libraries(copy_planner_lib ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2021-06-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jmyazbeck](https://answers.ros.org/users/74848/jmyazbeck/) on 2021-06-30**:
Thank you so much. Please do you mind explaining what was happening?

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2021-06-30**:
Its CMake's convoluted way of making sure that your code is linked against the proper libraries of base_local_planner.

**Comment by [thefakhreddin](https://answers.ros.org/users/114599/thefakhreddin/) on 2022-08-19**:
God bless you. it worked!!